# Tabs using action bar vs TabHost

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment-tab-host

I want to create a simple application where I can

1. Put tabs on the bottom of the screen
2. Edit the physical look/appearance of the tabs

On one hand, it seems that the most modern way to do this, for now, is using Action Bar:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

But it seems to me that it is not possible to do both using the tabs from the action bar.

To perform the two things I want, do I have to use TabHost, with fragments (the older way) or can I use the action bar tabs with fragments?

Comment: "Put tabs on the bottom of the screen" -- this is a UI anti-pattern on Android: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 2):

I use ActionBar tabs in my application, and I customize their look via android stles/themes.

In the theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabView</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then I define a style:

```
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView" name="MyTabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
</style>
```

Your 'drawable' can be a 9-patch, layer-list, selector, image, etc.

Comment: ok i'll check it out, thanks, and what about pushing the tabs to the buttom, i saw in some other threads to use uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow", but it doesn't work.

Comment: My bad -- I didn't address part of your original question -- feel free to continue to inquire more here.

Comment: Thinking about the android guidelines, they really don't want you to put tabs at the bottom (that's an iOS thing). I'm not sure you'll be able to do it without creating a custom view or TabHost. See some info here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2KZQJCUC6Bg

Comment: Thank you matt, It didn't occur to me that the ios thing would be the reason, so bottom line it looks like you can't. if anyone else has found a way please let me know, thanks again matt.

Comment: And for a citation, see http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html, "Don't use bottom tab bars"